# Validate if user account is active in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement account activation by e-mail link. My `User` model is very simple, inherits from `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`, so it has `is_active` field by default. Upon registration, new user is created with `is_active=False` param and I want to handle case, when user tries to log in and even though credentials are fine, should not be logged in because account is not activated. I'm using Knox Token Authentication. My serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework import serializers, exceptions


class LoginUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Account is not activated')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed()
```

And view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from knox.views import LoginView
from .serializers import LoginUserSerializer


class LoginUserView(LoginView):
    serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginUserView, self).post(request)
```

And with that code, I stumbled upon problem: when I try to log in with already activated account, everything looks fine, but when I try unactivated one, instead of `Account is not activated`, I get:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

Which I think, comes rather from view than the serializer.

Comment: Django can't not authorize inactive account. That's why you get this error

Comment: You're right, thanks! I've added `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']`  to `settings.py` and now I can log in with inactive account. But now I encountered another problem - it somehow skips the checks in `validate()` in serializer, meaning that even if an account is inactive but logged in, it passes `user.is_active` check and exceptions defined by me are not being raised at all (in both cases, if user and if user.is_active fails). What's even stranger, I've replaced exceptions with `return status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED` and still nothing.

Comment: Try to debug. Is your request reach at this point `user = authenticate(**data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so thanks to Shafikur Rahman suggestion I was able to make it work. After I tried to debug it with `pdb` and set trace inside `LoginUserSerializer` but nothing happened, I realized that in my views I'm not pointing to the serializer I wrote, but to `AuthTokenSerializer`. Even after that it still didn't work, because of my lack of understanding of how django `login()` and DRF `validate()` works. Below fixed code for reference:

view:

```
class LoginUserView(LoginView):
    serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = LoginUserSerializer(data=request.data)  # changed  to desired serializer
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginUserView, self).post(request)
```

and serializer:

```
class LoginUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()  # added missing fields for serializer
    password = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                data['user'] = user  # added user model to OrderedDict that serializer is validating
                return data  # and in sunny day scenario, return this dict, as everything is fine
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Account is not activated')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed()
```

Additionally to be able to `authenticate()` not active user, I had to add

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend'
]
```

in project settings.